# cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly from iinterface

Tags: c#, api

beloww is my interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
  {
   public Task<IApiResponseItem<T>> MyMethodt<T>(string inp1, string inp2,
  string inp3="SqlKey", ApiMethod method = ApiMethod.Get,
  TimeSpan? timeout = null) where T : new();
  }
```

and implementation

```
 public async Task<IApiResponseItem<T>> MyMethodt<T>(string inp1, string inp2,
  string inp3="SqlKey", ApiMethod method = ApiMethod.Get,
  TimeSpan? timeout = null) where T : new();
  {
  
  }
```

below is the call

```
var iApiResponse = await _resilentApi.MyMethodt(inp1, inp2, "SqlKey", ApiMethod.Get, timeout);
```

but, i always receiving error as

The type arguments for method 'IMyInterface.MyMethodt(string, string, string, ApiMethod, TimeSpan?)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Did you "Try specifying the type arguments explicitly" like the error suggests? Something like `_resilentApi.MyMethodt<SomeReturnType>(inp1, inp2, "SqlKey", ApiMethod.Get, timeout)`

Comment: With that semicolon, the code won't even compile. Please provide a [mre], i.e. some code that we can actually use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, just read the goshdarn error message. From what do you think should the compiler be able to determine (infer) the actual type for T there?

Comment: The compiler has no way to know what type the method is going to return so you need to tell it. Return types always need to be specified e.g. `_resilentApi.MyMethodt<MyClass>(...)`

Comment: I have even created simple method in interface like below   public Task<IApiResponseItem<T>> Test<T>() where T : new();  and treid to implement the same but, same error thrown.  I also tried  var test = _resilentApi.Test<IApiResponseItem>(); but, the error remains same

Comment: .Test<object>() this resolevd this issue, like xerillio said

Comment: @user20051042 It seems you might benefit from reading up on [what generics are and how to use them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics). What is `T` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass in a `string`, a `string`, a `string`, an `enum` and a `TimeSpan` to the method. You never specified `T` in the parameters of the method. How would the compiler be able to figure out what `T` is? It could be anything.

There are 2 possible solutions.

1. you need to specify the type as part of the method call.

   ```
   var iApiResponse = await _resilentApi.MyMethodt<Whatever>(inp1, inp2, "SqlKey", ApiMethod.Get, timeout); 
                                                   ^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. make `T` part of the method signature somewhere

   ```
   public async Task<IApiResponseItem<T>> MyMethodt<T>(string inp1, string inp2, T t,
        string inp3 = "SqlKey", ApiMethod method = ApiMethod.Get,                ^^^
        TimeSpan? timeout = null) where T : new()
   ```